# Installing newly developed R package in mac OS X el Capitan

Tags: r, macos, r-package

I just developed and released a package called `DiversityOccupancy` (version 1.0.2) in CRAN.

It passes every `R CMD check --as-cran`, and I have been able to install it in Ubuntu, and Windows without any problem. However, when I tried to install it on a Mac running OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan, it could not install it from CRAN, and the message I got was:

> ** preparing package for lazy loading Error : object ‘plot’ is not exported by 'namespace:raster'

however I checked, and that is on the `NAMESPACE` file in the Source.

Two questions,

1. Can anyone think a reason on why my package should not be compatible with mac? if you see the check link in CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_DiversityOccupancy.html It seemed that it passed every check in OS X El Capitan.
2. Could anyone try to install it on OS X to see if it works? (I don't have more Macs available in my circle), it might be a particular problem of the system I have available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that the raster package also has an error in the mavericks version of R https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_summary.html. That is, if a package that your own package depends on can't be installed in a version of R, it will be impossible for your own package to be installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download and install the latest version of `sp` and then `raster` from source, rather than as a binary package.

Comment: Thank you @RobertH I didn't think about it. do you have any idea of why Raster, and sp have errors in the mavericks version of R?. I was analysing the data from the link above, and it has a higher proportion of errors in the r-release-osx-x86_64-mavericks flavor.

Comment: I think it is because rgeos fails: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-release-osx-x86_64-mavericks/rgeos-00check.html; leading to a fail in an example of 'sp'. Hence 'raster' (and any other package depending on 'sp' is not available. That is pretty bad... Probably something that could be addressed in a next version of sp.